# Google maps ios url scheme leaving a review

Tags: google-maps

I'm trying to figure out the URL Scheme to to trigger Google maps to open right to the spot where you can review a business.

Tried everything from

```
comgooglemaps://search.google.com/local/writereview?placeid=ChIJ3TEKFllwcVMRGzGat2nA7H4
```

And

```
comgooglemaps://?q=Southland+Technical+Services+LTD,+5708+1+St+SE+%232,+Calgary,+AB+T2H+2W9&ludocid=9145896503567069467#lrd=0x53717059160a31dd:0x7eecc069b79a311b,3
```

But none of these appear to work. It works as normal URL in a web browser but in iOS app of Google maps it doesn't.

Does anyone have any ideas?